# How to get N number of gaps in SQL table column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named student data having two column **SINFO** and **SID**. **SINFO** having the range from ***G74001*** to ***G99999***. Below is the format of the table.

write a SQL query to get first n number (in this case suppose 3) of the gaps from '**SINFO**'.

In this case, the first 3 gaps are G74003, G74004, G74006. How to achieve this by SQL query. **SID** is a unique value.

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?  In either case, handling gaps and islands is going to be tough here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [identify gaps and islands](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/identify-gaps-and-islands) On the other hand, please read this: [The SQL of Gaps and Islands in Sequences](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Comment: create a table of all 'G's with numbers in range (1 - 100000), and use a left join. filter out the not nulls, and you will be left with the gaps.

Comment: creating one more table is not what required. I want to get gaps from the table and store them in some containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a temporary table that contains all the numbers
Then left join the base table
and select all the null values, or the top value, for example**

```
Create Table #Tmp
([SINFO] [nvarchar](50) NULL)

declare @ddd int =74000 
WHILE @ddd < 74015 
BEGIN  
   select @ddd= @ddd +1
   insert into #Tmp (SINFO)  values (  'G' + Convert(Nvarchar ,  @ddd ))
END;  

--all gaps
select  #Tmp.SINFO , Table_2.SINFO  from #Tmp
left join Table_2 on #Tmp.SINFO = Table_2.SINFO 
where Table_2.SINFO is null
order by   #Tmp.SINFO

--Frist gaps
select top(1) #Tmp.SINFO , Table_2.SINFO  from #Tmp
left join Table_2 on #Tmp.SINFO = Table_2.SINFO 
where Table_2.SINFO is null
order by   #Tmp.SINFO

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tmp') Is Not Null)
Begin
  Drop Table #Tmp
End
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the solution a little bit. What is table_2?

Comment: Table 2 is the table in which the data are located
I have created it for testing - Replace it with the name of the table where your data is located